# CSS Property refuses to change with either JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a Chrome bookmarklet for YouTube that will Stretch videos to a decent size, but for some reason I'm not able to change CSS Style values with either JQuery or vanilla javascript

First I found that Youtube apparently doesn't already include jQuery in the page so I ran the following:

```
  var js = document.getElementById('MyScript')
  if (js == null || typeof(js) == 'undefined' ){
     js = document.createElement('script'); 
     js.setAttribute('id','MyScript');
     js.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"; 
     document.head.appendChild(js);
  }
```

After that was taken care of I still could not edit CSS class properties using the following commands.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('html5-video-controls')[0].style.width = '1800px'
$('.html5-video-controls').css({'width':'1800px'})
$('.html5-video-controls').css('width','1800px')
```

Below is a snip from the Chrome Developer Console. 
[image: snip from the Chrome Developer Console.]

As you can see, the commands are having no effect. I am able to directly edit the values in Developer Tools by hand, but not programmatically.  What's going on here?

**EDIT**: More details:

I'm trying to modify the "Theater Mode" for the extension "Magic Actions For Youtube".  A picture of what it theater mode is is included below.  Basically I don't like all the dead space on the sides so I want to try to stretch it a little more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An !important declaration provides a way for a stylesheet author to give a CSS value more weight than it naturally has. make sure you have not set any such declaration before trying to change with js or jquery.
eg

```
.html5-video-controls{
    width:1000px !important;    
}
```

Comment: That is set by either Youtube or Magic Actions For Youtube.  Is it possible to change a property that is marked !important?

Comment: you may need to give some position property so that you can pull it out of the position static flow.